# No data has been sent through CasperJS ajax

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am working on Casper JS web scraping, for now I have scraped the title from a site. I am making ajax request to the php file where I am collecting the data through post, but the data is not being sent through it while the response status is `200 and OK` I don't know what is causing the problem.

The rest of the data is inserted successfully into the table, but not the title.

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start("https://www.google.com/");
casper.then(function(){
  var data = this.evaluate(function(){
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent;
    return title;
  })
  console.log(data);
  casper.thenOpen("http://localhost/fiverr/Crawl%20The%20Jobs/modal_scripts.php",{method:"POST",data:data+"&crawled_jobs=true"}).then(function(res){
    console.log(res.status);
  })
})

casper.run();
```

The PHP script, I am collecting data in :

```js
if (isset($_POST["crawled_jobs"])) {

  $title = $_POST["data"];
  $jobs_list_insert = "INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(null,'$title','nady','ahmad','kahn','yess','yesss')";
  $con->query($jobs_list_insert);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :

```js
var i = 0;
console.log("Data Length : " + d.length);

function sendData(i) {
  console.log("Posting Data...");

  casper.thenOpen("http://localhost/fiverr/Crawl%20The%20Jobs/modal_scripts.php", {
    method: "POST",
    data: "title=" + d[i].title + "&loc=" + d[i].loc + "&day=" + d[i].day + "&salary=" + d[i].salary + "&link=" + d[i].link + "&logo=" + d[i].compLogo + "&crawled_jobs=true",
    async: false
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.status);
    sendData(i + 1);
  })

}

sendData(i);
```